# Xcode doesn't copy XIBs

Tags: ios, xcode

For some reason Xcode 6.3 doesn't copy XIBs (in both mac and ios projects) until I update/save them. So if I do clean and build, no XIBs will be copied. There are no errors in build log.

But it works if I create a new simple project.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are they in the *Copy Resources* stage of the target's *Build Phase*?

Comment: Yes, they are. Anyway it seems to work now after deleting all dirs in DerivedData.